# SQL Script fails to execute when invoked from Java code but works in sql developer

Tags: oracle, triggers, sql-scripts

I'm facing the below mentioned issue while executing a sql script through Java but the same script executes fine in Oracle sql developer.
Reason is not clear to me.

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Could anyone suggest on how to resolve this issue ?

I tried importing this sql script into sql developer and it worked fine.
But when i try to execute it through java it fails.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER <SCHEMA_USERNAME>.TR$BIR_TSTATE_INFO BEFORE INSERT
ON <SCHEMA_USERNAME>.TSTATE_INFO
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.CID := <SCHEMA_USERNAME>.SEQ_TSTATE_INFO_CID.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

Comment: "I see an issue" - please edit your question and include the errors  you're encountering. Thanks.

Comment: You may just need to omit the `/` at the end, but without seeing the error you're getting, we can only guess (and probably be wrong).